# Skip part of execution on specific page

Tags: phoenix-framework

I have a plug that checks for data on every page, kind of like authentication. If they don't have at least one entry of data, they get redirected to a page to add an entry of the data. The problem is that it will keep redirecting them even if they are on that page. I still need to check the data on every page, but skip the redirect if it's on a specific page. I've tried pipelines, but it seemed overkill for what I need since I just need to skip one piece of the execution (the redirect). What's the best way to skip the redirect for a certain controller / action?

Plug

```
def add_default_team(conn, user, opts) do
    repo = Keyword.fetch!(opts, :repo)
    default_team = user.default_team_id

    if default_team do
      assign conn, :current_team, repo.get!(Team, default_team)
    else
      conn
      |> redirect(to: Helpers.team_path(conn, :new))
      |> halt()
    end
  end
```

The route I'm trying to avoid redirecting on would be the team_path(conn, :new)

Comment: You can check for the path in `conn` and don't redirect if it matches the target path. Can you post some code and more details about which route you want to not redirect?

Comment: Yep, updated with code from plug that fires on every page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the value of `conn.request_path` and skip processing it if it matches a certain string by adding this clause above the existing clause you have:

```
def add_default_team(%Plug.Conn{request_path: "/team/new"}, _user, _opts), do: conn
```

It would be better to use `path_info` though, since it removes consecutive and trailing slashes:

```
def add_default_team(%Plug.Conn{path_info: ["team", "new"]}, _user, _opts), do: conn
```